# Hot tub water does not get warm

Tags: temperature, hot-tub

We had repairs done to the hot tub.  Supposedly it is good to go.  I feel like there's something I should do with the control panel (buttons) in order to heat the water up.  I was able to set the desired temperature using the buttons, I think, but the water never gets warm.  We waited 24 hours before we gave up and turned off the power.  The model is "La Palma" made by Watkins.  The jets seem to work.  I've taken off the panel (cover).  Is there some heater component that should get warm, that I could touch to make sure is working?

Comment: Make sure all the electric breakers and/or gas are turned back on after the repair.  A worker will typically turn everything off before starting for safety.  There could be separate breakers for heat.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - The only thing I know to turn on is the circuit breaker which is a foot away from the tub.  That makes the control panel light up.  I don't think there's any gas involved.

Comment: Check the main breaker board - there might beca second breaker - look to make sure they are all on as relevant.

Comment: Do **NOT** "TOUCH" Anything  if you do not know what it is. :)

Comment: There are 2-3 safety’s on most hot tubs one for flow 1 for temp sometimes one on the heat element for open conductor, all 3 drop the power to the heat element, since it got “warm” it was working at some level but more would be needed on the controller to really help you out. Since your knowledge is limited it may be safer to call the repair person back, a standard sized portable hot tum usually has a 5kw or so heater these do take 8+ hours to achieve temp depending on the starting temp of the tub. Also some controllers are programmed to turn off the heat at specific times this may be your issu